# In MLP, in the formula to calculate the delta in the hidden layer, it uses the sum of all Deltas and Connection Weights in the next layer?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

**Reference:**
http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html

I have a question about the equation to calculate the delta in the hidden layer: In the formula to calculate the delta in the hidden layer, it uses the sum of all Deltas and Connection Weights in the next layer?

In this article that I mentioned, in the subtopic "Proof of the four fundamental equations (optional)", almost at the end of the article, where he mentions the BP2 equation to calculate the delta in the hidden layer in component form(Which I wrote below):

\begin{eqnarray}
  \delta^l_j = \sum_k w^{l+1}_{kj}  \delta^{l+1}_k \sigma'(z^l_j).
\tag{45}\end{eqnarray}

The expression he uses in formula has a summation with indices K and J. But I'm a little confused, I have a question: This summation of the BP2 equation in component form (i.e. it doesn't use matrix notation) means that the delta of a neuron in the hidden layer will be equal to the sum of the delta multiplied by the connection weight (that is, the weight that connects the output of the neuron in the previous layer with the input of the current neuron in the output layer), of each neuron in the next layer? **For example, If my neural network there was 1 neuron in the hidden layer and 3 Neurons in the output layer, so the formula would look like this:** `"deltaHidden1 = (deltaO1 * W11) + (deltaO2 * W12) + (deltaO3 * W13) + etc..."` ?, **is what I understand correct?  Did I understand this BP2 formula correctly?  Please, could someone help me understand and explain better?**